# windows xp like web app not working properly

Tags: jquery

I happen to be messing with JQuery lately, and I decided to make something like win xp where you have windows that you can: minimize, close, and maximize. And when minimized the window should be marked in a taskbar as minimized.

My code: http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/pen/xbaRJz

But you see, I happen to find the following problems in my code:

- When clicked in a window, the window does not increment `z-index`
- When clicking in minimize button of second window, *window 1* is marked as minimized instead of *window 2*
- I'm having a lot of trouble making a maximize button, these part is optional, but it would help a lot if you could tell me exactly how to do this

The code happens to be so complicated for my brain, that I could not identify where exactly the problems are. What I do know, is that the problems are between `line 42` and `line 124`. As you can see it is a wide range.

Sorry I can't do any better, I just don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Hi! Open up dev tools in your browser, place a breakpoint in line 73 (as measured by the "JS" pane) and look at what `id` is, and what `$(this).parents('.window')` is (hint: not scalar).
That aside, as external sites might change or vanish without SO having any control, moving relevant parts of the code into the question would help us keep the knowledge in here usable even in the future. Thanks! :)

Comment: Remove those w1 w2 variables. Take a look at [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: @gerdi This looks pretty interesting, but I still don't understand how I could use it. Sorry, I'm kind of a beginner in JQuery.

Comment: @Cornelius not trying to be offensive, but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @julianavar using clone you dont need the w1 w2 variables .

Comment: @gerdi yes, I understand that much. What you don't tell me is how. As I said before, I haven't worked with JQuery for more than 2 months so I'm still not used to it, could you please, explain?

Comment: @gerdi  The w1 and w2 variables are different though... He would still have to redefine some HTML code. Unless I'm mistaken, this would not help.

Comment: @julianavar Just read the spec and apply it . Instead of declaring the variables, in html strings, just clone what already exists.. [manipulate](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) html in jquery .. dont write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem regarding the minimizing issue is in this section of your code.

```
$(minimize).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parents(".window").id;
    $(this).parents(".window").css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    if(id = $(".w1")) {
      $(".app1").css({
        "background-color": "#aaaaaa"
      });
    } else if(id = $(".w2")) {
      $(".app2").css({
        "background-color": "#aaaaaa"
      });
    }
  });
```

This section of code seems to have two problems.

In this line of code, `var id = $(this).parents(".window").id;`, you are fetching the ID of the element .window, as opposed to the class.
In the HTML code for your windows, you have defined "w1" and "w2" as being classes (`<div class='window w2'>`), yet you are fetching the ID. What I suggest doing for now is to fetch the element itself, as opposed to the ID of the element : `var element = $(this).parents(".window")[0];`

NOTE : We appened the `[0]` because the function .parents() returns a list of elements. Since we expect that there will only be 1 item, we get the first item in the list, which is the item at index 0.

Now the reason why the window icon #1 always gets highlighted instead of the window icon #2 is in the following line of code : `if(id = $(".w1"))`.
When you want to compare the value of a variable to another value, you must use the "equal to" operator `==`. A single `=` is an assignment operator, which is used when you want to give a value to a variable.

Replace both occasions of `id = $(".w*")` with `element == $(".w*")[0]` and your minimizing issue should be resolved.

NOTE : I have changed the name of the variable from "id" to "element" for clarity, since we are not dealing with IDs anymore.

NOTE #2 : We appended [0] again because fetching elements matching a class will also return a list of elements. Since we expect that there will only be one "w1" and one "w2", we get the first element in the list.

Comment: Just noticed a couple of issues with my own code. Give me a second while I fix this.

Comment: It still not working, now the window icons don't get highlighted at all!

Comment: Do you know why the `z-index` is not incrementing?

Comment: now it's working, sorry, I didn't see your second edit

Comment: @julianavar Have you managed to make the z-index issue work out? I'll take a look at it if not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75583/discussion-between-cubia-and-julian-avar).